# Batch Script to rename computer and join to domain on a single click

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have 200 domain computers and i need to change the host name and rejoin to domain on a click.

1. First operation

```ps1
Powershell.exe "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass Add-Computer -DomainName <Domain Name> -ComputerName <Old_ComputerName> -NewName <New_ComputerName> -$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username = "<Domain\User ID>", ($password = <Password> | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force))"
```

2. Second operation

```bat
net user Administrator <Password>
```

3. Restart computer

But, While executing the above script in cmd with elevated privileges. I am getting the below error.

```ps1
At line:1 char:206
+ ... ement.Automation.PSCredential($username = Domain\User ID, ($passw ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

We are looking for a single line command to do the above operation.

Comment: So I assume the `$var` are replaced with the actual credentials when you run this?

Comment: At line:1 char:193
+ ... System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(domain\userid, (Passwo ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

Comment: May need to escape the nested double quotes with backslashes i.e. `"<Domain\User ID>"` to `\"<Domain\User ID>\"`. Or consider use of single quotes.

Comment: Why are you doing this at cmd.exe vs putting this is a real script and just running it in PowerShell directly? You don't need cmd.exe to do this, even for double-clicking. If the user does not have the permissions to join the computer to the domain, it will fail anyway, regardless of how you run this. These machines are not part of the domain now, so unless you are manually sending this script to the user via some email effort, how do you plan to get it on a host to have it run at all. If you are trying to use remoting, then it must be properly set up first. Don't use spacing in names.

Comment: Unless you are running PowerShell version lower the Windows PowerShell v5x, why are you doing this [net user Administrator <Password>], vs using the built-in PowerShell local users and groups cmdlets? What version of PowerShell is on each host where this script will be executed?

Answer (score 0):

This command syntax is not correct.

Do this is a script and run the script (deliver to users as an exe using the [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5) tool), thus no need for a batch file.

```
# Begin Script
$AddComputerSplat = @{
    DomainName   = <Domain Name> 
    ComputerName = <Old_ComputerName> 
    NewName      = '<New_ComputerName>'
    $credential  = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username = 'Domain\UserID', 
    ($password   = 'Password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force))
}
Add-Computer @AddComputerSplat
```

> Get-LocalUser
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1
>
> New-LocalUser
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/new-localuser?view=powershell-5.1
>
> Get-LocalGroupMember
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1
>
> Add-LocalGroupMember
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/add-localgroupmember?view=powershell-5.1

```
# End Script
```

Or if you just want to use cmd.exe and call the consoelhost, then this approach should work for you.

```
$Command = 'Add-Computer -DomainName <Domain Name> -ComputerName <Old_ComputerName> -NewName <New_ComputerName> -$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username = "<Domain\User ID>", ($password = <Password> | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force))"'
powershell -ArgumentList '-NoExit', 'NoProfile', '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass', "-Command  &{ $ConsoleCommand }"
```

Comment: `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Add-Computer -DomainName DomainName -ComputerName Old_ComputerName -NewName New_ComputerName -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\"Domail\UserID\", (ConvertTo-SecureString \"Password\" -AsPlainText -Force)))"` command gives the following error Add-Computer : Cannot add computer 'Old_ComputerName' to domain 'Domain Name' because it is already in that domain.

Comment: I am getting the following error when I tried to rename the computer. Error:- Rename-Computer : Fail to rename computer 'Old_ComputerName' to 'New_ComputerName' due to the following exception: Access is denied. Command which I used is as follows :- `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Rename-Computer -ComputerName "<Old_ComputerNmae>" -NewName "<New_ComputerName" -DomainCredential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\"Domail\UserID\", (ConvertTo-SecureString \"Password\" -AsPlainText -Force)))" -Force`

Comment: Invoke command gives Invoke-Command : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'credentials'. `powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass invoke-command "Old_ComputerName" -credentials (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\"Domain\UserID\", (ConvertTo-SecureString \"Password\" -AsPlainText -Force))) -script {Rename-Computer -ComputerName "Old_ComputerName" -NewName "New_ComputerName" -credentials (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\"Domain\UserID\", (ConvertTo-SecureString \"Password\" -AsPlainText -Force )))" -Force -PassThru}`